# delegate without parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

I got this code

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state) { MessageBox.Show("somethinghere"); });
```

Is there a way to do this better? I use `delegate(object state)` but I don't even need this, but when I use `delegate()` it gives me an error!

Comment: The `delegate() { ... }` means you do specify the arguments and that there are none. Since that is incorrect (it appears that the work item type is a delegate that takes one arguments and returns `void`, even though you don't show that code), you get the error. You meant `delegate { ... }` with no `()`. That means the argument list is not really used, so you omit it, but the compiler will know what it will look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { ... });
```

or

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply omit the argument list entirely:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { MessageBox.Show("somethinghere"); });
```

Or you could use a lambda:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => MessageBox.Show("somethinghere"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem expects a delegate as parameter declared as follow:

```
public delegate void WaitCallback(object state);
```

if you use delegate() it will give an error because you are not matching the delegate signature, that requires one object as input and a void as return.

You could use lambda expressions as follow:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => MessageBox.Show("somethinghere"));
```

Or you could create a method that matches that signature like this:

```
private void waitCallBackMethod(object state)
{
    MessageBox.Show("somethinghere");
}
```

and then use it on the call like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitCallBackMethod);
```